# Hyphenation Problem in LuaTeX after MiKTeX Update

Tags: luatex, miktex, hyphenation

I'm writing a document in German using LuaTeX on windows with a MiKTeX installation. I use some words with hyphens, e.g. Baden-Württemberg. Using the LuaTeX specific `\hyphenation{Ba-den=Würt-tem-berg}` worked find until I updated to miktex 2.9.6600 and LuaTex 1.07 lately.

Now, I cannot find a way to tell TeX the right hyphenation. With the old version, it would insert a hyphen at any specified position, if needed. With the new, only the `-` between Baden and Württemberg is used.

I made a MWE to show, that `\hyphenation` still works for normal words but not for those with dash:

```
\documentclass[ngerman,12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
    \hyphenation{Ba-den=Würt-tem-berg Fluss-be-tt}
\usepackage{showhyphens}
\begin{document}
    \parbox{0pt}{Baden-Württemberg}
    \parbox{0pt}{Flussbett}
\end{document}
```

The result should begin a new line at every possibility given by `\hyphenation`. But this does only work for "Flussbett":

[image: Resulting Document]

So either the usage of `\hyphenation` in LuaTeX has changed or this is a bug of the current version.

Can you confirm this or correct my usage of `\hyphenation`? And if it is an unknown bug, can you tell me where I can report it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! With the latest TeX Live 2017 I get the correct hyphenation.

Comment: Anyway, shouldn't it be `\parbox{0pt}{Baden"-Württemberg}`, where `"-` is the `babel` shortcut for "allow hyphenation in the words immediately before and after the hyphen"?

Comment: @TeXnician It is my understanding that MikTeX uses the latest TeXLive, so it should be based on 2017. Is that not the case? This is unlike distro versios on Linux, where (for example) the distro version un Ubuntu 16.04 is still 2015.

Comment: The latest version of LuaTeX that's distributed with TeXLive2017 is still 1.0.4. There's an intriguing announcement on miktex.org (see https://miktex.org/announcement/luatex-1-07) that as of today, i.e., 30 Jan. 2018, MikTeX2.9 is distributed with version 1.0.7 of LuaTeX, in both a "classic" version based on Lua 5.2 and an "experimental" version that employs Lua 5.3. Which version are you using?

Comment: According to the docu it should work, and according to my tests it doesn't (not only in miktex, but also if a newer luatex is used with texlive, and also in context). So it is imho a bug.

Comment: @RobtAll no miktex is not based on texlive and is often (as here) ahead of texlive in publishing luatex updates

Comment: @Mico I get no hyphenation in texlive2017 updated with luatex 1.07 (either version)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Thanks. Will LuaTeX 1.07 be pushed to general users of TeXLive2017 and MacTeX2017, to supersede version 1.04? Or are special efforts required to obtain version 1.07?

Comment: @Mico no it is in tl2018 (I compiled from source)  note even in 1.04 you do not need the babel `"-` convention, luatex can (could) hyphenate words with explicit hyphens

Comment: @Mico regarding your earlier question: I did not change my Lua engine to 5.3 so it should be 5.2. However, to my understandig this (should) only affects Lua code and not LuaTeX itself.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle MikTeX is not based on TeXLive? I learned something new. Actually, I was not referring to the executables, which apparently are custom to MikTeX, but only to the TeX-script packages available via CTAN. That is, with current MikTeX, I should be able to update something such as `hyperref` to the current version, rather than being locked into (say) TeXLive 2015 packages (as with Ubuntu 16.04 distro). Am I wrong?

Comment: @RobtAll with miktex as with texlive you normally get the packages from their respective package manager repositories rather than from ctan directly, but both miktex and texlive usually update from ctan within days, you can of course install packages from ctan "by hand" with any of miktex, vanilla texlive or a linux distribution texlive.

Comment: Am I right in assuming this issue does not persist?

Comment: @schtandard yes you are right, it is fixed in Tex live 2019 with LuaTex 1.10.0.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue does not persist in current LuaTeX versions.