# Compound word hyphenation problem (bug?) with LuaTeX 1.07.0 (TeX Live 2018)

Tags: luatex, hyphenation

**EDIT 2019/05/07:**

In LuaTeX 1.10.0 included in TeX Live 2019 compound word hyphenation works as expected.

---

As stated in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/162957/164311)
from 2014 and [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/301834/164311)
from 2016, LuaTeX should allow arbitrary hyphenation points for compound
words already separated by hyphens through:

```
\hyphenation{short=tem-pered}
```

I'm using LuaTeX version 1.07.0 included in TeX Live 2018 and this command
isn't working (though it seemed to work in earlier LuaTeX versions).

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{showhyphens}

\setmainlanguage{spanish}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\begin{document}

\hyphenation{cos-te=be-ne-fi-cio s-ib-a-rit-a}
%                  ^
%                  Should allow hyphenation for contiguous words

\textenglish{Equal sign hyphenation is not working:}

\parbox{0pt}{Coste-beneficio}

\parbox{0pt}{Coste}

\parbox{0pt}{Beneficio}

\textenglish{Silly example of (wrong) manual hyphenation, which works:}

\parbox{0pt}{Sibarita}

\end{document}
```

[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/412894/hyphenation-problem-in-luatex-after-miktex-update) from early 2018 is the only reference I found about this issue.

Are there any updates on this? LuaTeX 1.08 got released about a month ago, how can I check if this has been reported or fixed? Thanks!

Comment: It works with with luatex 1.09, Development id: 6930 and luaotfload 2.9.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Good! Will not stumble upon this issue in the future. Thank you. Is there a way to try out a recent version of LuaTeX for a TeX Live 2018 installation (through `install-tl-unx.tar.gz`) in a GNU/Linux system?

Comment: @undostres If you are using a x86-64 system, you can use my LuaTeX development repo for TeX Live.  Instructions are on the GitHub page: https://github.com/hmenke/texlive-luatex-dev